# odd prime division

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that if $p$ is an odd prime then $p$ divides

$\lfloor(2+\sqrt5)^p\rfloor -2^{p+1}$

---

I am struggling to progress with this question. Here is my working out so far:

[Page 1 working out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB6ug.jpg)

[Page 2 working out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOB1Q.jpg)

I don't know if I'm on the right track or if I'm heading to abyss.

Comment: You can prove more: 20$p$ divides that expression.

Comment: More generally see [PV (Pisot–Vijayaraghavan) numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let
$$N=(2+\sqrt{5})^p+(2-\sqrt{5})^p.$$
Note that $N$ is an integer. There are various ways to see this. One can for example expand using the binomial theorem, and observe that the terms involving odd powers of $\sqrt{5}$ cancel.

Because $(2-\sqrt{5})^p$ is a negative number close to $0$, it follows that
$N=\left\lfloor (2+\sqrt{5})^p\right\rfloor$.

In the two binomial expansions, all the binomial coefficients $\binom{p}{k}$ apart from the first and last are divisible by $p$. The first term in each expansion is $2^p$. We conclude that $N\equiv 2\cdot 2^p\pmod{p}$, and the result follows.

Comment: I follow your argument. Thanks. I imagine one uses the same argument for the generalised case  $p$$^n$ instead of *p*, for *p* an odd prime.

Comment: You are welcome. About $p^n$, one attempt at generalization is that $p^n$ divides $\lfloor (2+\sqrt{5})^{p^n}\rfloor -2^{p^n+1}$. However, this is false, $p=3$, $n=2$.